# How would you prove a set of vectors to be linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Suppose we have non-zero vectors $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v}$ with $\vec{v} \in$ span($\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$. Show that these vectors are linearly dependent. How would we do this?

Since $\vec{v_1}  \in$ span($\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2})$: $\vec{v} = \lambda_1\vec{v_1}+\lambda_2\vec{v_2}$

$
a_1\vec{v_1}+a_2\vec{v_2}+a\vec{v} = 0_{4,1}
\\
a_1\vec{v_1}+a_2\vec{v_2}+a({\lambda_1\vec{v_1}+\lambda_2\vec{v_2})} = 0_{4,1}
\\
(a_1+a\lambda_1)\vec{v_1} + (a_2+a\lambda_2) \vec{v_2} = 0_{4,1}
$

So if we were checking for linear independence, we would be saying that:
$$
a_1+a\lambda_1 = 0
\\
a_2+a\lambda_2 = 0
\\
a_1+a_2 = 0
$$
And try solving these equations right? (Correct me if I'm wrong)
But how would we go about trying to solve this?
Would we try solving this and not be able to get a solution meaning that the set of vectors is linearly dependent or do we use a counter-example to try and solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are doing, so it is hard to say whether it is wrong or not. The easy solution is this. Since $v\in span(v_1, v_2)$ for some numbers $a,b$ we have $v=av_1+bv_2$. Then $0=(-1)v+av_1+bv_2$. Since not all coefficients in that linear combination of $v, v_1, v_2$ are equal to zero but the linear combination is the zero vector, these vectors are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \dots, \vec v_n\}$ be a set of vectors in a vector space.

Consider the linear combination $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \vec v_k =a_1\vec v_1 + a_2 \vec v_2 + \cdots + a_n \vec v_n$.

We say that $\{\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \dots, \vec v_n\}$ is *linearly independent* if $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \vec v_k = \vec 0$ has no non-zero solutions.

Hence, $\{\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \dots, \vec v_n\}$ is *linearly dependent* if $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \vec v_k = \vec 0$ has a non-zero solution.

You have deduced, from $\vec v\in \operatorname{span}(\vec v_1, \vec v_2)$, that $\vec v = \lambda_1 \vec v_1 + \lambda_2 \vec v_2$.

Hence $\lambda_1 \vec v_1 + \lambda_2 \vec v_2 -\vec v = \vec 0$, which is a non-zero solution, showing that the vectors are linearly dependent. Notice that $-\vec v = (-1)\cdot \vec v$.